# Как сделать печать без диалогового окна?

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2

У меня есть компьютер с ubuntu 18. в браузере открываю сайт. На сайте есть кнопка "Печать". Мне надо, что бы происходила печать сразу, не вызывая диалогового окна. Это возможно сделать?

Сайт на yii2. Используется принтер чеков

Comment: https://www.websitesupport.info/hc/en-us/articles/205075144-Bypass-the-Print-Dialog-Box-in-Firefox

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не совсем то, что я искал. я нашел такое решение - https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp, но не могу понять, почему выдает ошибку Unauthorized

Comment: Я через escpos печатаю отдельным процесмом